# How to use seek pagination in SQL when going back a page? (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination

I want to create a pagination with seek method (by using an index).
On the first page I want to have the newest records (with the highest ids) so when I go to next pages the ids should be lower and lower.

Lets say I have 100 users in database. So my first query to get the first page would be this:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

To fetch another page I need to use index:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id < 90 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

And if I want to fetch next pages I just do `id < 80`, `id < 70` etc. and it works fine.
But what if I want to go page back?

Right now I do this: (change `<` to `>` and `DESC` to `ASC`)

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id > 89 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10
```

This fetches desired records, but the problem is they are sorted vice versa.

What I get:

```
90 | tom@gmail.com
91 | patrick@gmail.com
92 | jimmy@gmail.com
...
```

What I want to get:

```
100 | hannah@gmail.com
99 | dog@gmail.com
98 | hello@gmail.com
...
```

My questions:

1. Is my implementation of this pagination method correct? Maybe i'm doing something completly wrong?
2. If my approach is correct, how should I get the records in correct order? Is it possible to do it in SQL or the only way is to sort the results afterwards on the server?

Comment: instead of switching order and comparison operator you could increase your target id by 10? If you have gaps in your ids (and if the dataset is not large) you may want to use LIMIT/OFFSET.

Comment: @clamp My dataset is large, that's why i'm not using offset/limit. And there may be gaps so I cannot just increase the number by 10

Answer (score 1):

Get your rows with the current order is a sub query then resort on the outer:

```
select * 
  from (select * 
          from users 
         where id > 89 
         order by id asc 
         limit 10
       ) 
order by id desc;
```